# I have recieved messages informing me that a ip address is trying to view my computer remotely.

Tags: remote-access

How do I safeguard my computer from remote attempts to hack my system ? I have a HP G72 laptop and am running Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is to make sure that if you don't want remote login, to disable the SSH server on your computer. By default, it doesn't run, so unless you intentionally started it before, it shouldn't be.